# How to get standard output from subshell?

Tags: linux, shell, subshell

I have a script like this?

```
command='scp xxx 192.168.1.23:/tmp'
su - nobody -c "$command"
```

The main shell didn't print any info.
How can I get output from the sub command?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of its output by just redirecting the corresponding output channel:

```
command='scp ... '
su - nobody -c "$command" > file
```

or

```
var=$(su - nobody -c "$command")
```

But if you don't see anything, maybe the diagnostics output of scp is disabled?
Is there a "-q" option somewhere in your real command?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually running the scp. When you use the

```
VAR=value cmd ...
```

syntax, the `VAR=value` setting goes into the environment of `cmd` but it's not available in the current shell. The command after your `-c` is empty, or the previous value of `$command` if there was one.

Comment: It did ran, the machine 192.168.1.23 can receive the file.

Comment: All right then, you must have had `$command` set already, or you're using a shell (which one?) that doesn't behave like any I've seen. Or you really have a semicolon in there that you didn't mention. In an case, what output are you expecting?